# How to programatically take a screenshot in Sprite-Kit?

Tags: ios, uiimage, screenshot, sprite-kit

I've been reading resolved questions on how to programmatically take a screenshot but I can't seem to get what I've read to work in sprite kit. For instance:

This question [How to take a screenshot programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically)

```
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.window.bounds.size);
    [self.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [data writeToFile:@"foo.png" atomically:YES];
```

UPDATE April 2011: for retina display, change the first line into this:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.window.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
else
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.window.bounds.size);
```

gave me this information, which I tested on my game but it didn't work because window was not recognized on an SKScene. I tried replacing it with scene but that didn't work. Any suggestions?

I also tried this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, scale);
[self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Which I found in this question: [ios Sprite Kit screengrab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19571357/ios-sprite-kit-screengrab)

But it didn't seem to work either because it didn't recognize scale, or bounds in the second line.

Comment: Not work as in blank image or only partial? What content do you have on your screen when the screenshot is executed?

Comment: It's the game over menu, which displays the users highscore, and I want to execute it when the user taps the twitter or facebook button, then attach it to the share post. So I want it to save to the app if possible, so that it can be referenced in the social sharing with "share.png" if that makes sense. @sangony

Comment: The way it didn't work was because it didn't recognize scale in the first line, and in the second line it didn't recgonize self.bounds @sangony

Comment: That is exactly what I do in my app!! Check it out https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/save-square-squares-adventures/id967632086?mt=8 ! I didn't want the user to cheat so i take a screenshot as a proof!!

Answer (score 6):

**This is the best solution to take a screen shoot in your Sprite-Kit**

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, 1);
[self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return  viewImage;
```

Comment: [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES]; - Is causing game to slow down is there any way to slove this issue

Answer (score 3):

```
func screenShot() {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size, false, 0)
    self.view!.drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.view!.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    var image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    var Image = image //The image is stored in the variable Image

}

screenshot() //Calls the function and takes a screenshot
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Full Screen Shot function. Hope this will work well in spritekit.   
func screenShot() -> UIImage {                                                    
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height))
 var context:CGContextRef  = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
 self.view?.drawViewHierarchyInRect(frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
 var screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();  
 return screenShot 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can take screen shot for a any view.`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *gameOverScreenImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();`

Comment: Do I just place this inside of a button method? and where does the image save.

Comment: Yes, you can put it inside button method. 'gameOverScreenImage' has that image. YOU CAN USE IT AS YOU LIKE.